# Loading cell values in dataGridView from text file C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, streamreader, streamwriter

I am using a StreamWriter to write all values on all exisiting cells in a dataGridView, that writer is working perfect. But my reader isn't doing its work very good.

This is my writer code(which has no problem):

```
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(valuePath);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(cell.Value);
            }
        }
        writer.Close();
```

This is my reader code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(valuePath);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Value = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
```

The output:
**Monday**
**1**
**Tuesday**
**2**
**Wednesday**
**3**

This code is reading each line from the txt file into the "existing cells" in my dataGridView, so when the app is opened, there is only one row. That's why my reader is not working good. Can someone help me solve this??

Comment: `That's why my reader is not working good`? be more specific is it reading the text file to cells or not? if possible give us the **current output** and **desired output**

Comment: do you mean if you have multiple rows and columns defined when app is opened, the reader code is working correctly?

Comment: Yes it is reading the text file to cells. The output in the text file is the desired one, the problem is the reading method I'm using

Comment: Chris: your last statement didn't add a single hint! what is your **current output** (edit the question please)

Comment: OK!  when the app is opened there is only one row!! how many rows you want out there?

Comment: There should appear three, as you can see, there are three days, so three rows.

Comment: and when you read your text file by a text editor what do you see there?

Comment: Monday 1 Tuesday 2 Wednesday 3. But the writer isn't the problem.

Comment: Your writer writes each cell in a new line. This will make it hard to read back. Write each row in 1 line. In your read, you got to move to next record in the file, you are not doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you write your text file in this format:

cell1, cell2, ...

cell1, cell2, ...

cell1, cell2, ...

...

to do that, change your `writer` code to :

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(valuePath);
string line;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    line = "";
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        line += cell.Value.ToString();
    }
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
writer.Close();
```

The `reader` code should be changed accordingly to:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(valuePath);
string line;
string[] values;
int n=0;

while(!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    values = line.Split(',');

    for(int m=0; m<values.Length; m++)
    {
       dataGridView1[m, n].Value = values[m];
    }
    n++;
}
sr.Close();
```